# How to run laravel app using docker-compose?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Following is what I tried, is there something I doing wrong?

**step1. create a simple laravel app at localhost.**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel-app 5.6
```

**step2. create docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
    php:
        image: php:7-fpm
        ports: 
          - "3021:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
    composer:
        image: composer:latest
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
        working_dir: /app
        command: ["install","php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0"]
        depends_on:
            - php
```

After that, I run **docker-compose up --force-recreate -d** and access **127.0.0.1:3021** at browser, but I get nothing.

Then I run docker-composer log, it shows me this error message:

```
Invalid argument php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0. Use "composer require php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0" instead to add packages to your composer.json.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing commands. Composer does not "serve". Php has a build in dev server to "serve".

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick

To actually get Laravel up and running please do the following:

1 - Run this in the `laravel-app` folder: `composer install`

2 - Create a Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev openssl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

3 - Build your docker image: `docker build -t my-laravel-image .`

4 - Finally replace the content of your docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: my-laravel-image
    ports:
        - 3021:8000
    volumes:
        - ./laravel-app:/app
```

A more complete tutorial can be found here (not mine): https://www.techiediaries.com/docker-compose-laravel/

**EDIT:**

in order to use the official compose image you could simply do this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    composer:
        image: composer:latest
        working_dir: /app
        entrypoint: php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
        depends_on:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
        ports:
          - "3021:8000"
```

**Make sure `./laravel-app` contains a laravel project. Otherwise this won't work!**

Comment: Thanks man, but can I using php and composer offical image to do the same thing?
Is that possible to use links、networks or depends_on to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

in the main folder of your Laravel app, create a file named Dockerfile and insert this code:

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

In the same main folder of Dockerfile, create a file named docker-compose.yml and insert this code:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8009:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c 'php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yourdbname
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: yourpassword
```

Open the terminal command line and go inside the laravel folder, and launch this commands:

```
docker.compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

if have need to create and migrate the db, or use other commands, launch the Laravel commands in this way:

docker-compose run app php artisan
The app will available at the address http://0.0.0.0:8009

Source: https://medium.com/@pierangelo1982/dockerize-an-existing-laravel-application-with-docker-compose-a45eb7956cbd